# What suhosin patch works with php 5.3.28?

Tags: suhosin

I'm running PHP 5.3.28 on my openvz VPS and want to recompile my PHP with Suhosin.
But it seems suhosin does not released any patch for my PHP version.
Should I use 5.3.2 suhosin patch instead?

Any help will be appreciated